# Java 8 - Once Stream is consumed and operated giving error, but in another case its not

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am new to Java 8 and looking to understand the difference between the two scenarios. I know that once a stream is operated and consumed then stream cant be reused again it will give an error.

**Scenario-1:**

```
List<String> title = Arrays.asList("Java8", "In", "Action");
        Stream<String> s = title.stream();
        s.forEach(System.out::println);
        s.forEach(System.out::println); // THIS WILL GIVE ERROR - streams has been already operated and closed.
```

When I run this, I get below error... which is fair.

```
Java8
In
Action
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.sourceStageSpliterator(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.Java8InAction.CH4.TraversableOnlyOnce.main(TraversableOnlyOnce.java:12)
```

**Scenario-2:**

```
// Filtering unique elements
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4);
numbers.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
numbers.stream().filter(n -> n % 2 == 0).distinct().forEach(System.out::println);
numbers.stream().filter(n -> n % 2 == 0).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here also I have operated stream and closed the terminal operation, then why I did not get any error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two calls to `s.forEach` utilise the same stream hence the exception in the first example whereas the call to the [**`stream()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) method --> `numbers.stream()` *generates (yields) a new stream each time* hence doesnt throw a *"java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed"*.

Answer (score 5):

`.stream()` creates a new instance of a `Stream` despite the fact it's called on the same collection

Answer (score 1):

Because a stream can be consumed only once. if you want to use multiple time use [**Supplier**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) for this.

```
Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier = ()-> Stream.of("Java8", "In", "Action");
```

then use `get` to create a new stream.

```
streamSupplier.get().forEach(System.out::println);
```

but in second scenario you create a new stream every time.

Comment: Could you please add more details and I did not follow you

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` is a terminal operation.

> After the terminal operation is performed, the stream pipeline is considered consumed, and can no longer be used;

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html